# How to include an WASM npm module in svelte with vite?

Tags: svelte, webassembly, vite, wasm-pack

I'm using vite to run a svelte app, and have a WASM package built with `wasm-pack --target web`. If I use the package directly with vanilla JS, I can write something like:

```html
<script type="module">
    import init, { greet } from "./pkg/compiler.js";

    init().then(() => {
        greet("Hello");
    });
</script>
```

in an HTML file where `greet` is one of my `wasm_bindgen` functions, and that works fine.

However, my intended pipeline is to publish the `pkg/` folder that `wasm-pack` generates to npm, and then use this package in svelte with vite, something like so:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import init, { greet } from "@ocr-compiler/compiler";
    
    init().then(() => {
        greet("Hello");
    });
</script>
```

However, this throws an error:
`Unknown file extension ".wasm" for /home/drbracewell/code/ocr/packages/svelte-editor/node_modules/@ocr-compiler/compiler/compiler_bg.wasm`
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Vite docs mention that it will automatically process `.wasm` files, but does this not happen when they're included from npm packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually solved this using [vite-plugin-wasm-pack](https://github.com/nshen/vite-plugin-wasm-pack/), but a couple notes:

- You need to bundle with the `--target web` flag with `wasm-pack`.
- If your rust crate exists locally you should just be able to pass path in and the plugin will bundle it correctly.
- If you intend to publish your package to or are using a WASM package from `npm`, you will need to add a `main` property to the `package.json` generated by `wasm-pack` - There's currently a pull request open to ensure that it will get added regardless of the target, but in the meantime it would be pretty simple to setup a package script that adds it to the JSON.