# Nuxt3 - how to use vite-plugin-wasm

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, webassembly, nuxtjs3

I'm building a Nuxt3 application where I need to import and use a 3rd party node package which internally is using webassembly.

In my case, the package I need is https://github.com/higumachan/lindera-js

#### Where do I import the package?

In one of my components, right at the beginning of the `<script>` tag.
And afterwards I'm using it in one of the methods.
(Note: I removed unnecessary code below)

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import * as lindera from "lindera-js";

...

  methods: {
    doTranspile() {
      const tokenized= lindera.tokenize(this.input);
      console.log(tokenized);
    },
  },

...

</script>
```

---

#### What is the Problem?

After dev server compiles everything and I reload the page in the browser, I get the following error:

```
[vite] Internal server error: "ESM integration proposal for Wasm" is not supported currently.
Use vite-plugin-wasm or other community plugins to handle this.
Alternatively, you can use .wasm?init or .wasm?url.
See https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#webassembly for more details.
```

#### The Question

How can I use the package without problems in Nuxt3? Do I have to use `vite-plugin-wasm` and if so, how and where to use/import it?
Or is there any other way to use a package which is using webassembly?

I found some similar questions on SO, but not sure if they can be used like this in Nuxt3 as I'm fairly new to Nuxt in general.

- [How to use embedded Webassembly in Vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571129/how-to-use-embedded-webassembly-in-vite)
- [How to include an WASM npm module in svelte with vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72587871/how-to-include-an-wasm-npm-module-in-svelte-with-vite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `vite-plugin-wasm`

```
npm i -D vite-plugin-wasm
```

Add the plugin in vite in the `nuxt.config.ts`

```
import wasm from 'vite-plugin-wasm';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        plugins: [wasm()],
    },
});
```